# Angular Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time when new project created

Tags: angular

When I'm starting a new project in angular, for example (`ng new -the name-`), it shows me an error at the end

```
ng new proofangular8
```

Output:

```
CREATE proofangular8/Angular.json (3675 bytes)

CREATE proofangular8/package.json (1248 bytes)

Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:/ws/deps/uv/src/win/core.c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an angular-cli issue. It means the system clock is drifting.

You can try doing a CMOS reset on your system to fix it.

Check [this thread](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1633).

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I had the same issue with firebase on Windows 10. I simply synchronized the clock. There is a button called "Synchronize Your Clock" under Date & Time settings. And the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using node via nvm and probably future me;

In Windows 10 `nvm use 12` installed node version 12.0.0. Changing the version to the current latest release of 12.22.4 with `nvm use 12.22.4` resolved the issue.

I guess it's a bug with nvm since nvm in Linux using the same command `nvm use 12` installs the latest minor version of node 12, hence why people saying that using WSL works fine.